# Get top N weighted GPS points in bbox

Tags: elasticsearch, gps, gis, geospatial, postgis

Given a large list of GPS coordinates and their weight, is there an open source software (database/search engine) to get top N values inside a bounding box or a circle?

```
SELECT * FROM list WHERE IS_IN_BBOX(coords, bbox) ORDER BY weight DESC LIMIT 10;
```

I expect the list to be in tens of millions of items. The bounding box might be very large (whole world) or very small (zoom 18), but the search should still be reasonably fast. Also, could we use Elasticsearch for that?  I saw that it has a distance based search, but not weight based search.  How about Postgis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can can use [ST_MakeEnvelope](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeEnvelope.html) and && operator

```
SELECT *
FROM list
WHERE list.coords && ST_MakeEnvelope(left, bottom, right, top, srid) 
ORDER BY list.weight;
```

repleace left, bottom, right, top and srid accordingly to search

Comment: Thanks @Czejeno, but how efficient is this search? If the bbox is half of the whole world, with 10 million rows, will it be able to use proper indexes to pick the result efficiently?

Comment: I've seen also few "math" answers regarding this problem but && operator seems more optimized by postgis :) 
Also make sure u have spatial index on coords in table, an look at http://postgis.net/docs/performance_tips.html